# The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. X-RequestDigest

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have an HTML form that I am trying to send (POST). And I keep getting the following 403 error: `The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.`

I have read several other posts and tried the accepted answer (make another request before my Post to `_api/contextInfo` and I continue to get the same error

```
value: "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
```

Here is my updated script per Dylan Cristy's answer:

```
fetch("/_api/contextinfo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
}).then(contextResponse => {

    // get the form digest value that you _would_ have gotten from $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()

    var requestDigest = contextResponse.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

    // now use it in your next request

    fetch("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(LeaveRequestPost)/items", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
            "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Now I am getting the following issues:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FormDigestValue').
```

The response in the Network Tab shows as contextInfo and contains the value shown below, but when I console.log contextResponse, it does not provide .GetContextWebInformation.

```
{
  "d": {
    "GetContextWebInformation": {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.ContextWebInformation"
      },
      "FormDigestTimeoutSeconds": 1800,
      "FormDigestValue": "FormDigestValue_Value",
      "LibraryVersion": "LibraryVersionValue",
      "SiteFullUrl": "SiteFullUrlValue",
      "SupportedSchemaVersions": {
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
        },
        "results": [
          "14.0.0.0",
          "15.0.0.0"
        ]
      },
      "WebFullUrl": "WebFullUrlValue"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this code running on a SharePoint page/site? Also, are you using/loading jQuery?

Comment: Hey Dylan, it is running on a SharePoint site, it is a custom html page which I converted to .aspx, the operations I am running don't require any of the default .aspx sharepoint scripts so I don't think that would be an issue.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery on your custom page?

Comment: Yes, I am loading jQuery

Comment: You should post your new error about the primitive value as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when you're making a request to `/_api/contextinfo` to get around not being able to get the request digest from

```
$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
```

you have to wait for the response, and then use the returned form digest token in your next request in the same `"X-RequestDigest"` header.  It's not enough to just hit the endpoint with a `POST`.

```
fetch("/_api/contextinfo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
}).then(contextResponse => {

    // get the form digest value that you _would_ have gotten from $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()

    var requestDigest = contextResponse.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

    // now use it in your next request

    fetch("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(LeaveRequestPost)/items", {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
            "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
        }
    });
});
```

Note that in my example, in the first request I changed to `odata=verbose` because I was just verifying on a SP 2013 site and you have to use `odata=verbose` on 2013, and if you change to `odata=nometadata` it might change the structure of the response slightly. I'm guessing there won't be a `d` property so it might be something more like

```
var requestDigest = contextResponse.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
```

In any case, the idea is the same - you hit the `/api/contextinfo` enpoint to get the form digest value, but you have to then *use* that value in your next request.

---

I forgot you are using `fetch`, and when you use `fetch` the response object doesn't automatically resolve into the JSON data you requested, you have to call `json()` on the response to get the JSON data (which is another async operation). So you'll need to do something like this:

```
fetch("/_api/contextInfo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
}).then(contextResponse => {

    // when using fetch you have to explicitly
    // get the response json which is another async operation

    if (contextResponse.ok) {

        contextResponse.json().then(responseJson => {

            // get the form digest value that you _would_ have gotten from $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()

            var requestDigest = responseJson.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

            // now use it in your next request

            fetch("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(LeaveRequestPost)/items", {
                method: "POST",
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                body: JSON.stringify(item),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
                    "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
                }
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use this method, I no longer the previous error when but I do get this error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GetContextWebInformation')```. When looking at the response in the network tab, I do get the value for the formdigestvalue

Comment: In regards to the above comment, that was with the d property in requestDigest. When I remove the d property, I get the following ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FormDigestValue')```. Please see the update to my post with an example of the response

Comment: it shows in the Network tab as contextInfo, when I console.log contextResponse there is no GetContextWebInformation

Comment: @BeerusDev updated my answer

Comment: That fixed that issue, but now I am receiving another error. Please check the update to my OP if you are available

Comment: In my test list I updated the Employee (Person or Group Field) to a Single line of text, but I need it to be able to post to a person or group field