# Unable to update list item using POST and REST, but able to preform other POST tasks. Using Python Requests and Sharepy

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, python

I'm able to authenticate and run GET and POST commands.  But I am unable to update a list item.  Or create a new list item.

I'm using Python Requests and Sharepy(handles authentication).  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the request:

```
data = {"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.PythonRequestTestListItem"},"Title": "Test"}

headers = {"X-RequestDigest": "#__REQUESTDIGEST", "Content-Length": str(len(data)), "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"}

r = s.post("https://txtechnician.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('PythonRequestTest')/items",  data=data, headers=headers)
```

Here is the response:

RESPONSE CODE:

403

HEADERS:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8', 'Expires': 'Wed, 22 Jun 2022 16:21:37 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 07 Jul 2022 16:21:37 GMT', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'P3P': 'CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"', 'Set-Cookie': 'rtFa=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; domain=sharepoint.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly, FedAuth=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; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly', 'X-SharePointHealthScore': '1', 'DATASERVICEVERSION': '3.0', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-DataBoundary': 'None', 'X-1DSCollectorUrl': 'https://mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/', 'X-AriaCollectorURL': 'https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/', 'SPRequestGuid': '45ba4ea0-b0d3-1000-ff96-4b9d58303a66', 'request-id': '45ba4ea0-b0d3-1000-ff96-4b9d58303a66', 'MS-CV': 'oE66RdOwABD/lkudWDA6Zg.0', 'X-RequestDigest': '0x09A47EB759680E76C22812217579CF3E224992F14DD8E6B63E8530AC8FDADEC2D061EACB06EEB4B0A95335B8BC886D1B44DA0BF6C80CE950077FD9B6964BCA8A,07 Jul 2022 16:21:37 -0000', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com;", 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices': '16.0.0.22622', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireReadOnly', 'X-Cache': 'CONFIG_NOCACHE', 'X-MSEdge-Ref': 'Ref A: 8D958824F5794B07BE08174A9E808A2F Ref B: SN1EDGE1522 Ref C: 2022-07-07T16:21:37Z', 'Date': 'Thu, 07 Jul 2022 16:21:36 GMT'}
```

TEXT:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2130575251, System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."
        }
    }
}
```

CONTENT:

```
b'{"error":{"code":"-2130575251, System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."}}}'
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the wrong value for the `X-RequestDigest` header.

What you appear to be sending there is just the string "`#__REQUESTDIGEST`".

You may have seen that string in other examples of making `POST` requests from JavaScript using jQuery, something like:

```
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
```

To explain what's going on there, you have to understand that for most of those JavaScript examples, the code is running on a page that is hosted in SharePoint, and for pages hosted in SharePoint, SharePoint adds a hidden `<input>` element in the HTML of the page that has `id="__REQUESTDIGEST"`, with the value of the request digest token valid for that page and user.

If you're using jQuery, you can get the value of that hidden field (i.e., the actual digest token) by using a CSS selector of "#__REQUESTDIGEST" to get the element with the `id` of `__REQUESTDIGEST`, and then getting it's value (`.val()`). This:

```
$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
```

says:

> Hey jQuery, go find me the HTML element on the page that has an id of "__REQUESTDIGEST", and give me the value of that element.

You can also do the same thing with vanilla JavaScript, if you're not using jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
```

That will get you the same digest token to use as the header value.

However... You're using Python, so I'm guessing your code is not running on an HTML page hosted in SharePoint, and therefore don't have access to a hidden `<input>` element to get the token value from.

There is another way to get a valid digest token to use in the header.  Essentially you need to make a `POST` request to

```
<your site URL>/_api/contextinfo
```

and in the response from that request, you can get a form digest value at:

```
responseJson.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
```

that you can then use in the `POST` request where you are trying to add a list item and need a valid `X-RequestDigest` header.

See [this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/302502/8992) for more explanation/details.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to get the FormDigestValue as you mentioned. I updated the X-RequestDigest to be that new value.  and I'm still getting the 403.  The returned DigestValue = 0xE9374D25F3152B22B0388617C0802381A7718DBC0548F52ACC87A24B3698DC1E6882DB2EB32DDD88B320FFB002396924B8B7597F97B40E2CCE5190EB70F32725,07 Jul 2022 18:05:11 -0000  Is it possible I'm missing something else?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the right format for the digest token.  I guess it is possible you're missing something else, but nothing else really jumped out at me from your code samples, sorry.  Is it still the same error message: "The security validation for this page is invalid..."?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dylan Cristy's answer I was able to solve part of the problem.  The other part of the problem resided in sharepy.  Here is the rest of the solution for those who need it.

**Sharepy's Problem**
The header for the authorization token isn't properly named in the current version:  [Github Issue](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy/issues/49)

*To correct this you have to update the header value.*

```
s = sharepy.connect("https://{Your Site}.sharepoint.com", username='{your email}', password='{your pass}')
```

*Updating the header:*

```
s.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + s.auth.digest})
```

**Second part of the problem:**

To create an item in SP following this Microsoft example: [SharePoint REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#create-list-item)

There must be an "X-RequestDigest" token.  To get that token using python you must make a call to the site within the same session by using:

```
x = s.post("https://{Your Site}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Your Sub-site}/_api/contextinfo")
```

**Get the "FormDigestValue" which will be the "X-RequestDigest" token:**

Create a dictionary to extract the token:

```
_thedict = json.loads(x.text)
```

Create a variable to store the token:

```
_token = _thedict["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"]
```

**Construct the JSON (in this case I'm adding an item to a list called "TestList") to be sent:**

```
data = {"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.TestListListItem"},"Title": "Test"}
```

*Note:  to get the "type", you need to submit the following request and pull it from the response:*

```
r = s.get("https://{Your Site}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Sub Site}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/listItemEntityTypeFullName")
print(r.content)
```

**Update the header values as per Microsoft's example:**

```
headers = {"X-RequestDigest": _token, "Content-Length": str(len(data)), "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
```

**Send the request:**

```
r = s.post("https://{Your Site}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Sub Site}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/items",  json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Nice, you were able to figure it out and get it to work!  Well done! :)